# Получить расширение файла при парсинге через Curl PHP

Tags: php, curl

Подскажите, каким образом можно узнать типа (расширение) файла при парсинге?

```
function curl_download($url, $file){
    $dest_file = @fopen($file, "w");
    $resource = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.com/");
    curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_FILE, $dest_file);
    curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($resource);
    curl_close($resource);
    fclose($dest_file);
}
curl_download("https://www.com/download.php?id=6107", ROOT . "/file.torrent");
```

Мне приходится самому указывать расширение файла, но там может быть и картинка и zip.

Comment: [curl_getinfo](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-getinfo.php) может пролить свет

Comment: @ArchDemon не удается получить расширение с помощью этих параметров к сожалению.

Comment: Там может быть не расширение, а тип содержимого. По нему можно предположить расширение

Comment: @ArchDemon application/force-download

Comment: Разве оно не совпадает с $file?

Comment: Это означает что клиенту нужно отдавать файл на скачивание в наглую, а не тип его.

Comment: Есть ещё один вариант. Загрузить файл, а от него взять `finfo_file()` или `mime_content_type()`

Comment: Буду пробовать, о результате обязательно отпишу.

Comment: В итоге, через Curl не вышло проверить тип файла. Сделал так: загрузил файл на сервер с расширением .tmp, затем проверил через mime_content_type() и изменил расширение.